# Is it possible to combine a gate and an approval to limit an Azure deployment?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure, you can limit deployments with gates and approvals. Gates are usually some sort of status or health check. Approvals require a certain user or group to manually approve the deployment.

Is it possible to combine the two?

For example, I'd like for a deployment to require an approval but only if it's before 8 am or after 5 pm.

Another example would be to require an approval if the application is not live (liveness would be determined by a REST call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to create "conditional approvals" this way. You can schedule Gates and/or approvals but can't make one dependent on the other. The only thing you can configure is to ignore the gate and still ask for approvals or ask for approvals and then run the gates.

But what you can, using a custom release gate (Azure Function for example), is to do the required check and then use the Azure DevOps REST API to edit the release instance. An azure function with the right permissions could [either enable or disable the approvers on the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#approvalstatus) or [override an approval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

An example of how to do this can be found here:

- https://abelsquidhead.com/index.php/2017/12/25/creating-async-custom-automated-release-gates-in-vsts-with-rest-api/
- https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/gates.md
- https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/tree/master/ServerTaskHelper/DistributedTask.ServerTask.Remote.Common